# Replace one Dataframe with Values from another but persisting some data in the original

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes like this

```
  DF1 

  name        age    surname   previous_surname 
  Andrese     20     William   William
  Jancy       25     Thomas    Thomas
  Andronella  22     Harry     Harry
  Amelia      21     Jack      Jack

  DF2

  name        age    surname   
  Andrese     20     Harrison   
  Jancy       25     James   
  Jessica     22     Litpick
  Amelia      21     -
```

1. I want to replace the DF1 with DF2 on name and age
2. I want to keep any records that are missing from the DF2 but appearing on DF1 alive
3. I want to add anything that DF1 doesn't contain but is contained in DF2 to DF1. Basically I want an all inclusive DF which looks like this.

   ```
     name        age    surname   previous_surname 
     Andrese     20     Harrison   William
     Jancy       25     James      Thomas
     Andronella  22     Harry      Harry
     Amelia      21     Jack       Jack
     Jessica     22     Litpick    -
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need merge with combine_first

```
df =pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['name', 'age'], how = 'outer').replace({'-': np.nan})
df['surname']=df['surname_y'].combine_first(df['surname_x'])
df = df.drop(['surname_x', 'surname_y'], axis = 1)

    name        age previous_surname    surname
0   Andrese     20  William             Harrison
1   Jancy       25  Thomas              James
2   Andronella  22  Harry               Harry
3   Amelia      21  Jack                Jack
4   Jessica     22  NaN                 Litpick
```